# How can I declare a struct?

Tags: c++, struct, declaration

I am currently learning C++ and trying to understand the usage of structs.

in C++. As far as I'm aware, if you want to define a function after the main() function, you have to **declare** it beforehand, like in this function (Please tell me if I'm wrong with it):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void printText(std::string); // <-- DECLARATION

int main()
{
    std::string text = "This text gets printed.";
    printText(text);
}

void printText(std::string text)
{
    std::cout << text << std::endl;
}
```

My question now is if there is a way to do the same with structs. I don't want having to always define a struct before the main() function, just because I prefer it like that. However, I get an error when I try doing it like that:

```
//THIS program DOESN'T work.    
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Products {std::string}; // <-- MY declaration which DOESN'T work

int main()
{
    Products products;
    products.product = "Apple";
    std::cout << products.product << std::endl;
}

struct Products
{
    std::string product;
};
```

When I delete the decleration and instead define the struct **before** the main function, the program works so I assume I'm somehow wrong with the decleration:

```
//THIS program DOES work
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Products
{
    std::string product;
};

int main()
{
    Products products;
    products.product = "Apple";
    std::cout << products.product << std::endl;
}
```

Could someone tell me if there is some way to declare a struct like that? Bear with me if I have any major mistake in the code, I'm just a beginner.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `struct Name;` is a forward-declaration you're looking for.

Comment: you should post the exact error message along with the question

Comment: How is this offtopic?

Comment: A forward declaration won't work here, as main() uses members from the struct.  You have to define the struct before main.  If you dislike the aesthetics, put the struct in a header.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pre-declare (forward-declare) a class type in C++.

```
struct Products;
```

However, a class type declared in this way is *incomplete*. Incomplete types can only be used in a number of very limited ways. You will be able to declare pointers or references to such type, you will be able to mention it in non-defining function declarations etc., but you will not be able to define objects of such incomplete type or access their members.

If you want to define objects of class `Products` or access members of class `Products`, you have no other choice but to fully *define* the class before such use.

In your case you are defining an object of type `Products` in `main` as well as accessing members of class `Products` there. This means that you have to completely define `Products` before `main`.

Comment: @AnT _"you have to completely define"_ I think declaration is enough.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : I'm not sure what you mean. The OP's usage requires class *definition* to be visible from `main` (i.e. a defining declaration is needed, as opposed to a non-defining one).

Comment: @AnT The ole confusion about _declaration_ and _definition_. A forward declaration isn't a full class _declaration_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ With all due respect, you seem to be the one who is confused about the accepted terminology.

Comment: @TimSeguine Be assured I'm not.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Then enlighten me as to what you think a "full declaration" is according to the standard. What would a "full declaration" look like syntactically, given that the standard defines no such nomenclature?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Well, to be precise, formal terminology does not include the concepts of "forward declaration" or "full definition". In the formal terminology we have: 1) *class declarations* that also happen to be *class definitions* (or simply *class definitions*, or what I call "defining declarations"), 2) *class declarations* that do not define the class  (or what I call "non-defining declarations"). "Forward declaration" is an informal name for 2. "Full declaration" is a reference to 1, to which I added the word "full" (or "complete") just to reinforce my point and reinforce the distinction.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: In C++ every definition is a declaration at the same time (with few non-germane caveats). Which is why *declaration* is a very vague and confusing term in a discussion about the matters of "defintions vs. non-defintions".

Comment: @AnT In that particular case, yes. Though the terminology is a bit of screwed up and misleading for the current example.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case a forward declaration wont help, because a forward declaration only allows you to use pointers or references, as e.g. in

```
struct foo;
foo* bar(foo f*) { return f;}
struct foo { int x; }
```

However,

```
struct Products {std::string};
```

is not a declaration, but if you want an ill-formed declaration and definition.
The correct forward declaration would be:

```
struct Products;
```

Comment: I didn't read very carefully to be honest, but I didn't downvote either. I would suggest to switch first and second part of an answer because first one is kind of irrelevant to the given question.

Comment: @Andrey good point. actually I added the last sentence only later. As I understand the question it is about forward declaring a struct in general and OPs code just serves as an example